# Delete duplicates using secondary data criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns of data (with headers) where A (sequential) always has duplicates (sometimes 2-3), however B data (also sequential) is always unique and dupes are non-existant. I found this solution from @Jeeped and modified to fit needs - obviously doesn't work since I don't know how to define max(B) within code.

```
Sub RemoDupeMaxB()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Set wb1 = Workbooks(“Survey Beta.xlsm")
With wb1.Sheets("VERT SCALES")
    lr = Application.Max(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
      .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    For i = lr To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value > '??? And _
          (.Cells(i, 2).Value > Max(B:B)) Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

What I want vba to do is to use the criteria of max(B) to delete (rows) all other dupes from A - that is keep the max(B) row data.

Comment: If both columns are on same sheet, when you delete rows, aren't you deleting data in B as well or is B only serving as a key? Not sure what you mean by max(B) or what you're trying to do that can't be done by the remove dupes button via the ribbon. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes. B is to be deleted as well, since all I am interested in the max value of B and it's associated A column data (which just so happens to be a dupe).  The below code from @Matt Cremeens works. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would approach this problem with a double-for loop, like so

```
Sub RemoDupeMaxB()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Set wb1 = Workbooks(“Survey Beta.xlsm")
With wb1.Sheets("VERT SCALES")
lr = Application.Max(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
  .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    for j = i - 1 to 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(j, 1).Value And _
          .Cells(i, 2).Value > .Cells(j, 2).Value Then
            .Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked exactly as I need.  For some reason the Set wb1 command didn't work, so I just set it to ActiveWorkbook since the file will be a template file and saved as its respective project name.